# Export Invoice Data with Suffix

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have an invoice database which allows invoices to be updated. This data is exported to an accounting software which does not allow invoices to be updated. So the idea is to suffix subsequent invoices with -1, -2 etc. To illustrate:

| date | invoice_number | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/01/2024 | INV001 | $200 |
| 05/02/2024 | INV001 | $25 |
| 05/02/2024 | INV002 | $350 |

The export on 31/01/2024 would be INV001, $200
The export on 05/02/2024 would be INV001-1, $25
And so on.

Just wondering if there is a clever way to do this as my plan below feels clunky/old school?

I think what I have to do is create a separate table to track invoice exports for example:

| Invoice_number | counter |
| --- | --- |
| INV001 | 1 |
| INV002 | 0 |

I'll have to run this in a few steps, first select data to be exported, then a scan loop to check a) was it previously exported and if so what is the counter and b) update counter+1 or add if first time with 0.

Comment: This is a bad idea for *business* reasons. You can't modify financial transactions or documents that have already occurred, you make compensating transactions. When you go to a store to return a faulty garment they don't scribble over your old receipt, they issue a return. If you buy a new product, you get a new receipt.

Comment: *my solution below* What solution?

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos has alluded to there is a good reason that accounting software does not allow invoices to be updated - because it shouldn't happen!! You could have an "Exported" flag on the invoice and allow it to be updated if this is false, but once exported you should generate a new accounting document with a new invoice number etc. Since you then wouldn't need to consider how to deal with amending invoices that have already been exported your requirement to increment the invoice number goes away

Comment: fair point, not a solution, a plan.

Comment: This is a business problem ,not a technical problem. In fact, `an invoice database which allows invoices to be updated.` is probably *not* what's really going on. I suspect there are drafts that get finalized before anything is sent to the accounting software. I also suspect that any changes are recorded separately, even if the UI shows the current state. What you need to send to the accounting software are the changes, not the modified invoice.

Comment: Seems an obvious way would be using `row_number() over(partition by invoice_number order by date) - 1`

Comment: Yep I get all the reasons why invoices should never be updated. Its a legacy system which allows items like shipping and other adjustments to be added to an invoice. Normally the final export to accounting is a summary by sale. Now they want it by invoice to aid bank reconciliation.

Comment: Which is exactly why you can't do what you plan, *especially* when it comes to reconciliation. You need to export the "changes" separately. As you said, the *summaries* were exported up to now which means the actual transactions are in the database.

Comment: I repeat. This is a business problem, not a technical problem. You can't make decisions that affect the company's accounting and can easily violate regulations. Ask the business people, or rather the accounting department, what should be done.

Comment: BTW I'm working on reconciliation reports for quite some years now. It's a mess, and sometimes even Accounting and Finance doesn't know how to handle some case but I know even less. I can propose some things but in the end it's a business problem. The accounting people  will have to change the way they work to handle individual transactions so whatever you produce should match *their* expectations. In an audit, *they* will have to explain the extra invoices